# How can I extract unique hex from string?

Tags: hex, unique, extract

How can I extract a unique hex number among MANY hex numbers in a sequence? I know that the sequence has no delimiters, ends with '.', and all hex numbers are with length 5. And If the number is not unique (i.e.the searched one) then will be repeated even times.

Example Input/Output:

```
input: abab1bca98abab1.       
output: bca98

input: 44444111112222244444222224444444444. 
output:11111

input: 01aefabcdeabcde01aef01aefb00b501aef. 
output:b00b5
```

Here is my attempt:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int convertToHex(std::string piece)
{
    int hex = std::stoi(piece, 0, 16);
    return hex;
}

int main()
{   
    std::string seq;
    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false); 
    std::cin >> seq;

    std::vector<int> hexVec;

    size_t SIZE = seq.length()-1;

    int counter = 0;
    std::string hex("");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        hex += seq[i];
        counter++;
        if (counter == 5)
        {
            hexVec.push_back(convertToHex(hex));
            counter = 0;
            hex = "";
        }
    }

    size_t vecSIZE = hexVec.size();

    /*for (size_t i = 0; i < vecSIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << hexVec[i] << std::endl;
    }*/

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecSIZE; i++)
    {
        int currEl = hexVec[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < vecSIZE; j++)
        {
            if (currEl == hexVec[j] && i != j)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (j == vecSIZE - 1)
            {
                std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
                std::cout << std::hex << hexVec[i];
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me:
Test #5 (Incorrect answer) 
Time used: 0.178 s
Memory used: 2.36 MB

Test #6 (Memory limit) 
Time used: 3.770 s
Memory used: 6.59 MB

Test #7 (Memory limit) 
Time used: 3.769 s
Memory used: 6.71 MB

Test #8 (Runtime error) 
Time used: 0.178 s
Memory used: 8.89 MB

P.S. I do not know what are the tests. This is neither my homework nor a exam or smthn. It's just an outclass problem that I found with a judge system.

Comment: So what does your code do wrong that you want help with?

Comment: they want to do it within 3.000s and using only 5MB memory, so there must be another way.